# Percent increase between two values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I created this sql query:

```
select "Období", sum(Cena),"Skupina zboží", "Zkratka skupiny", "Firma"
from
(select CASE when fav.VATDate<DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) and  fav.VATDate>=DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) then '3 až 6 měsíc zpětně'
                  when fav.VATDate>=DATEADD(month, -3,GETDATE()) then '3 měsíce zpětně'
        END "Období"
       ,pro.Ce_Jedn * pro.Mnoz "Cena"
       ,zbo.SkZ "Skupina zboží"
       ,CASE WHEN  charindex('-', zbo.skz) > 0 then substring(zbo.SkZ, 0, charindex('-', zbo.skz)) 
                  else zbo.SKZ
        END "Zkratka skupiny"  
       ,baz.fir "Firma"
from PRODEJ pro
inner join FAKTVYDA fav on fav.Ci=pro.C_Fak and fav.Rada=pro.R_Fak
inner join ZBOZI zbo on zbo.Cis=pro.C_Zbo 
left join ZAKAZKA zak on zak.Ci=pro.Ci and zak.Rada=pro.Rada
left join ZAKAZNIK baz on baz.cdo=fav.cdo
where pro.datp > -2 and fav.VATDate>=DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) tab
group by
"Období","Skupina zboží", "Zkratka skupiny", "Firma"
```

and result of this query is something like this:
[Result http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/9903/s1q6.png](http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/9903/s1q6.png)

Now I need to add one more column, in which will be percent increase between "3 až 6 měsíců zpětně" and "3 měsíce zpětně". Is here any way how can I achieve this?

edit
This maybe help for better imagine
[image: Second image]

Comment: What column are you doing the percent increase calculation on? Column 2 (No column name)?

Comment: Yes, columnt 2 (no name column). Each firm in column "Firma" have number for "3 až 6 měsíců zpětně" and "3 měsíce zpětně" and I need to get the percent increase (or decrease) between them.

Comment: Look, this is the same question you asked yesterday. The problem is that you don't have the values for `3 až 6 měsíců zpětně` and `3 měsíce zpětně` on different columns (even if you later present them on a reporting tool that does this). That column makes sense there, or if you already calculate the dataset the same way

Comment: what relevance do all the other columns have here?

Comment: @Lamak it can still be done however, using CTE, Pivot() over() or even derived tables

Comment: @Yakyb I know it can be done. The point is that the column needed makes sense on the particular presentation layer that s/he needs, and op isn't showing the result needed on this question

Comment: @Lamak 
That's why I come here. I know it's not possible to resolve this with any easy way.

Comment: @Sk1X1 But you would get better answers if you present us with, for instance, a sample data of the desired result. As the way it is, a column with the percent increase between 2 values from different rows, does litte sense. So, why don't you help us help you and show us what it is that you need

Comment: @Yakyb 
I'm not sure, if I understand you right. But I add one picture to my question. Image shows how I see result of query later.

Comment: @Lamak
I try to draw image with result, which I need.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Lamak
2008 R2 version

Answer (score 1):

Ok, even if you **still** didn't actually show us the result that you want (where is the column with the percent increase on your picture?), I believe that this is what you need:

```
SELECT  [Zkratka skupiny],
        [Skupina zboží],
        [Firma],
        [3 až 6 měsíc zpětně],
        [3 měsíce zpětně],
        ([3 až 6 měsíc zpětně]/NULLIF([3 měsíce zpětně],0) - 1)
        *100 [Percent Increase]
FROM (  SELECT  SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN fav.VATDate < DATEADD(MONTH,-3,GETDATE()) 
                            AND fav.VATDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) 
                        THEN pro.Ce_Jedn * pro.Mnoz
                    END) [3 až 6 měsíc zpětně],
                SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN fav.VATDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3,GETDATE()) 
                        THEN pro.Ce_Jedn * pro.Mnoz
                    END) [3 měsíce zpětně],
               zbo.SkZ [Skupina zboží],
               CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', zbo.skz) > 0 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(zbo.SkZ, 0, CHARINDEX('-', zbo.skz)) 
                    ELSE zbo.SKZ
                END [Zkratka skupiny],
               baz.fir [Firma]
        FROM PRODEJ pro
        INNER JOIN FAKTVYDA fav 
            ON fav.Ci=pro.C_Fak AND fav.Rada=pro.R_Fak
        INNER JOIN ZBOZI zbo 
            ON zbo.Cis=pro.C_Zbo 
        LEFT JOIN ZAKAZKA zak 
            ON zak.Ci=pro.Ci AND zak.Rada=pro.Rada
        LEFT JOIN ZAKAZNIK baz 
            ON baz.cdo=fav.cdo
        WHERE pro.datp > -2 
        AND fav.VATDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,-6, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY zbo.SkZ,
                 CASE 
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', zbo.skz) > 0 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(zbo.SkZ, 0, CHARINDEX('-', zbo.skz)) 
                    ELSE zbo.SKZ
                 END,
                 baz.fir) tab
```